# Сложение двух больших чисел

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, biginteger

Большие числа реализую как массив `unsigned __int64[8]`. Как реализовать операции сложения и умножения для таких чисел?
Нашел пример алгоритма на [сайте](http://ikit.edu.sfu-kras.ru/files/15/l17.pdf), но реализовать правильно не могу. Кажется, что из-за перевода в числа по основанию?

```
class BigInt {
public:
unsigned __int64 number[8];

const BigInt operator+(const BigInt& rv) const
{
    BigInt res;
    unsigned __int64 carry = 0, t = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        t = number[i] + rv.number[i] + carry;
        carry = t % ULLONG_MAX;
        res.number[i] = carry;
    }
    res.number[7] = t;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Пардон, это не вы задавали точно такой же вопрос пару дней назад?

Comment: @VladD я. Надеюсь эта попытка будет более удачной.

Comment: Согласно правилам сайта, так делать нельзя. И чем вам не угодили данные ответы?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3946/10105

Comment: Ваш вопрос по сути дубликат вашего же предыдущего вопроса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почему бы вам не отдать выполнение вычислений компилятору? Ограничьтесь хранением в массивах значений типа `unsigned long` - тогда с переносами все станет проще:

```
unsigned long long carry = 0, t = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    t = (unsigned long long)number[i] + (unsigned long long)rv.number[i] + carry;
    carry = t >> 32;
    res.number[i] = t&0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

Если ну очень нужно работать с 64 битами - нужны специальные действия по проверке переполнения, описанные в "*Алгоритмических трюках для программистов*" Генри Уоррена, второе издание, стр. 52.

Comment: дело в том, что уже много логики реализовал используя этот тип. Спасибо, изучаю.